# Could one control a software GUI with python?

Tags: python, hardware

I need to create a python script to control a ThorLabs device. The device can be controlled with the proprietary Kinesis software, coding with C#, or through the communication protocol commands (at least I think so, not experienced with this). I am working on the latter since I need this to work in python but I believe it's going to take me a while to learn how to do this.

So, I was wondering, would there be an easier way to prototype a quick solution say by letting python control the Kinesis software GUI? If not, would it be possible to call on a C# script through a python script? I'm not proficient with C# and our whole solution runs on python.

Some insight or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: C# wouldn't be a script, but a compiled program. you can create a CLI app with C# and give it command line arguments and then have the python app call that.

Answer (score 1):

[PywinAuto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto) seems like something that may work for you.